# Pin Color not Changing

Tags: ios, mapkit

I created an if-then statement to show a purple pin if the title of the pin is "HQ". The green pins show up correctly. Does anyone know why my pin color for the purple pin is still red?

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])

    {
        static NSString *annotationIdentifier=@"annotationIdentifier";

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

        if(annotationView)
        {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
            if([[annotationView.annotation title] isEqualToString:@"HQ"])
            {

                //The pin for the HQ should be purple
                annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
                [annotationView setAnimatesDrop:YES];

            }
            else
            {
                //All other new pins should be "green" by default
                annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
                annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
                [annotationView setAnimatesDrop:YES];

            }
        }


        return annotationView;

    }

    return nil;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the map reuses annotation view (or offers to do so)

same as a tableView does cell reusing.

---

now upon init you set the pin color, but on reusing you don't. so one pin is always the same color.

use different reuse identifiers for the different cases!

```
 static NSString *annotationIdentifier= ([annotation.title isEqualToString:@"HQ"]) ? @"HQ" : "OTHER";
```